# rails server will not start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal

When I try to run my rails server, I get the following error:

```
/Users/yedidyaweiner/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-      4.1.1/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:63:in `initialize': undefined   method `arity' for :versions:Symbol (NoMethodError)
from /Users/yedidyaweiner/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/associations/builder/collection_association.rb:18:in `initialize'
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to config/environments/development.rb

Set config.eager_load = true

Comment: What happens when run rbenv local 2.1.0 and then rails s then try with rbenv local 2.1.2 if that doesn't work